# I got nothing while i expect echo something after enter 123 to below script

Tags: shell, termux

I want to print a sentence when enter 123 but nothing happened without error. What is going on. This script for testing with no extra script in it's file.

```
fun1() {
echo "plz entr ur name"
read $user
if [ "$user" = "123" ]
then
        echo "su & zo"
        exit
fi
}

fun1
```

Comment: It would help if you replaced the generic `shell` tag with one that specifies the actual shell you're using. Also see the description of the tag you applied! Also, I'm not 100% sure what you're doing and in what order exactly.

Comment: I'm testing termux dear

Comment: [edit] your question to complete the info there. The comments are not a good place for that.

Comment: Although i had the answer, but I did it, it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

`read` takes the name of a variable to populate.

```
read user
```

`read $user` is equivalent to `read`, when `$user` expands to the empty string. If this is `bash`, then `read` will populate the variable `REPLY` instead. `if [ "$REPLY" = 123 ]` would work in that case.

But you really just want to to call `read` with the correct argument.

Comment: Thanks dear, it works, I missed the point you mentioned.

Comment: `$user` isn't a variable name; it's a parameter expansion of the variable `user`. The *result* of that expansion is used as the name that `read` will use, but if `user` isn't defined, the unquoted expansion produces  no value, leaving `read` without an argument.